# XSLT: Is it possible to select unique IDs into variable ordered by a criteria other than the ID itself?

Tags: xslt

Imagine the following xml

```
<elements>
  <element>
    <elementID>0x1000</elementID>
    <elementSort>1</elementSort>
    <elementName>Master Joda</elementName>
    <modifyDate>1979-01-01</modifyDate>
  </element>
  <element>
    <elementID>0x1000</elementID>
    <elementSort>1</elementSort>
    <elementName>Master Yoda</elementName>
    <modifyDate>1979-01-05</modifyDate>
  </element>
  <element>
    <elementID>0x2000</elementID>
    <elementSort>2</elementSort>
    <elementName>Luke Skywalker</elementName>
    <modifyDate>1979-01-08</modifyDate>
  </element>
</elements>
```

I use the following xslt to select a list of unique IDs into a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="ids" 
   select="elements/element/elementID[not(.=following::elementID)]" />
```

Then i let xslt build some html for each ID (the output will be a horizontal list of elements per ID)

```
<xsl:for-each select="$ids">

  <xsl:variable name="elementID" select="." />

  <div class="itemContainer clear" style="width:{$containerWidth}">

    <xsl:for-each select="/elements/element[elementID=$elementID]">

      <xsl:sort select="modifyDate" />

      <xsl:call-template name="elementTemplate" />

    </xsl:for-each>

  </div>

</xsl:for-each>
```

The problem is: how can i sort the elements in the first level of the for-each nesting (the IDs) without having the Element by which i want to sort in the list itself (the ID list).

In practical terms: how can i sort by Jedi hierarchy (master -> pupil), if elementSort 1 means master and elementSort 2 means pupil, having multiple elements per hierarchy in each row, which are then ordered by modifyDate.

Comment: This is quite unclear -- on reading the question several times, the answer is: Why just not add `<xsl:sort select="elementSort"/>` ?

Comment: Because i make the list of IDs unique at first. The 1st Level of for-each just iterates over the unique ids, but at this point i do not have the elementSort anymore.

Comment: See my answer how this can be done.

Comment: @Dimitre sorry, i had a typo in the inner for-each, it should look like this now, but this still does not solve the problem, of having the list of unique IDs in a specific order

Comment: ovm: My solution still must produce the wanted output. Just try it.

Comment: Your solution does not consider the outer for-each that is building the div-container for each "jedi". The "Rows" implemented by left-floating divs in these div-containers would be then ordered by modifyDate, but the div-containers itself should be ordered by the rank, the elementSort: the first "Row" should be elementSortID 1, the second 2 and so forth. The problem is, that i only want one div-container per "jedi" but i have multiple elements per jedi, because there can be different versions of one Entity. Your solution would not provide means to build up that 2-dimensional "grid".

Comment: ovm: If so, then you must edit the question and explain all this *there* clearly. Please, also provide the exact wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of**:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/elements/element/elementID[elementID=$elementID]">        
  <xsl:sort select="modifyDate" />        
  <xsl:call-template name="elementTemplate" />      
</xsl:for-each>
```

**BTW, the above is obviously incorrect**, because an `elementID` element doesn't have any `elementID` child at all.

**use**:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/elements/element[elementID=$elementID]">        
  <xsl:sort select="elementSort" data-type="number" />        
  <xsl:sort select="modifyDate" />        
  <xsl:call-template name="elementTemplate" />      
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: What i want to achieve is to overcome the "bad" design of the XML structure. Basically the XML should reflect what i want to achieve, but this is not possible at this time. So i want to "normalize" the XML Data by XSLT means

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution though it is probably not very good "xslt-design".

I store list of the unique elementSorts in an additional variable and put another for-each around the original first one. Then i combine the conditions (uniqueness and sortID) while setting the variable holding the unique element IDs.

```
<xsl:variable name="ids" 
   select="elements/element/elementID[not(.=following::elementID) and ../elementSort=$sort]" />
```

edit:

probably even better:

```
<xsl:variable name="ids" 
   select="elements/element[elementSort=$sort]/elementID[not(.=following::elementID)]" />
```

**another note**

if there are other nodes in the xml document that can contain elementID nodes, than you would have to specify the following:: clause as follows to avoid unwanted behaviour:

```
<xsl:variable name="ids" 
   select="elements/element[elementSort=$sort]/elementID[not(.=following::element/elementID)]" />
```

That way only elementIDs inside of element nodes are taken into consideration for evaluating the uniqueness, comes in handy if there were nodes that relate to the element nodes by elementID.